# Teletype IO getLine function

Tags: haskell, io

I have this data type:

```
data Teletype a = End a
            | Get (Char -> Teletype a)
            | Put Char (Teletype a)
```

A value of this type can be used to describe programs that read and write characters and return a final result of type `a`. Such a program can end immediately (`End`). If it reads a character, the rest of the program is described as a function depending on this character (`Get`). If the program writes a character (`Put`), the value to show and the rest of the program are recorded.

I have to write a Teletype-program `getLine` which reads characters until it finds a newline character, and returns the complete string. So far, I have this:

```
getline = Get (\c -> if c == "\n" then (Put c (End c)) else getline )
```

But it doesn't compile because

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
• In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘"\n"’
  In the expression: c == "\n"
  In the expression: if c == "\n" then (Put c (End c)) else getline
```

Comment: Note that this only returns the last character, not the full string. For the latter, you need some more tricky recursion. As a hint, consider a helper function `go :: String -> Teletype String`, where the first string argument represents "the characters read so far".

Comment: @chi do I need State to remember the characters already read? I don't yet understand how to store the data

Comment: You don't need `State`. You can define `go oldState = ....... (go newState)`. Changing the argument value models the "state update".

Comment: @chi something like this: `go x:xs  = if x == '\n' then End xs else Get (\c -> goUpdate (c:str))` ? But I don't understand how to pass and store the read characters anywhere

Comment: That's close enough. My untested code is `go str = Get (\c -> if c == '\n' then End str else go (str ++ [c]))` and then `getline = go ""`. (It's not efficient as it could be, but that's not important.) The idea is that you read `c`, and if it's not a newline you append it to `str` and recurse, reading the next char, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c` is a `Char`, indeed, the data constructor says `Get (Char -> Teletype a)`. `"\n"` is not a `Char`, that is a `String` (so `[Char]`).

You can compare with a new line, by comparing with `'\n'` (notice the single brackets):

```
getline :: Teletype Char
getline = Get (\c -> if c == '\n' then Put c (End c) else getline)
```

As @chi says, this is not this does not is a complete solution to the exercise. This fixes a local problem, such that you can continue solving it.

Comment: Note that, while this fixes the immediate issue, the program does not satisfy the requirement "reads characters until it finds a newline character, and returns the complete string". To me, this calls for `Teletype String`, no `Put` at all, and some clever recursion. It is best if the OP does this than spoiling the answer, though, since it's a nice exercise.